# Android - Trying to test a service on boot (java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, adb, boot, android-broadcast

I've been trying to test a service when a device boots up on android, but I cannot get it to work.
I'm trying to start it with this command from CMD:

(in ..\AppData\Local\Android\sdk\platform-tools)

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

or

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -c android.intent.category.HOME -n net.fstab.checkit_android/.MyReceiver
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.tabache.sciopero">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"/>


    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />

    <application
        android:name="com.example.tabache.sciopero.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <!-- Declaring broadcast receiver for BOOT_COMPLETED event.  PER FARE UN SERVIZIO AVVIATO ALL'INIZIO -->
        <receiver android:name="com.example.tabache.sciopero.MyReceiver" android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

        <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:exported="true">

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity><!-- ATTENTION: This was auto-generated to add Google Play services to your project for
     App Indexing.  See https://g.co/AppIndexing/AndroidStudio for more information. -->
        <meta-data
            android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
            android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

my receiver class is this:

```
public class MyReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    System.out.println("MyReceiver !!!!");
    Intent startServiceIntent = new Intent(context, MioServizio.class);

context.startService(startServiceIntent);
}
}
```

the answer to my dos command is this:

```
Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED cat=[android.intent.category.HOME] cmp=net.fstab.checkit_android/.MyReceiver }
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=3715, uid=2000
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1683)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1636)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3507)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:772)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:404)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(NativeMethod)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

Why I have this error "java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial"?

Answer (score 37):

I had same problem and solve by this:

```
 Try restarting ADB in root mode: adb root
```

and then broadcast BOOT_COMPLETED like this

```
 adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED 
 -p yourpackage.app
```

Comment: Yes, in this way it works! I run then broadcast with this istruction: "adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" without  "-p yourpackage.app"

Comment: If it says "adbd cannot run as root in production builds", refer to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45668555/1000551

Comment: PSA: `adb root` only works on rooted devices or emulators *without play services*. Thanks!

Comment: I did `adb root` and now I'm constantly getting `Broadcast completed: result=0`.

Answer (score 19):

If adb root is not working (Production build),
Use in your manifest :

`android:name="android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED` instead.

and from terminal:

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED
```

Comment: @AbhirojPanwar In this answer, first few words are: "If adb root is not working...". Root is simply not available in production builds.

Comment: inside the <receiver> ...</receiver> declaration under <intent-filter>

Comment: Worked for me. What's the difference between BOOT_COMPLETE and ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED?

Comment: @LifeQuestioner, the latter is not a system Intent, it could be "DonaldDuck" and it would be the same. So, be sure to modify it only for testing.

Comment: @Ron____ The answer doesn't work. ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED isn't a system intent. when you send the broadcast of this intent from the command line, you will get the message "Broadcasting: Intent { act=android.intent.action.ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED }
Broadcast completed: result=0"
But the OP wants to broadcast system intent BOOT_COMPLETED.