# Android BOOT_COMPLETED Permission Denial

Tags: android, android-intent, broadcastreceiver, bootcompleted

I would like to test my boot receiver (android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED) on a real device running Android 7.1.1
I tried to use this command from the command prompt:

> adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED -p [package_name]

but it returns ad exception:

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=11114, uid=2000
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1684)
    at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1637)
    at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3537)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:772)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:404)
    at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
    at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

I've already tried the solution offered by [Android - Trying to test a service on boot (java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40698450/android-trying-to-test-a-service-on-boot-java-lang-securityexception-permiss) but it doesn't work for me.

How can I solve this?

Thanks in advance! :)