# cannot reboot Android from terminal

Tags: android, user-permissions, android-reboot

I need to restart my app often to test the behavior of some components. So I want to use a `cmd` from terminal in order to not waste time closing / opening manually. I have found this code but when I put on the terminal it returns a permission error.

**CMD** **to reboot from terminal:**

```
adb shell am broadcast -a android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED
```

**Terminal Response:**

```
java.lang.SecurityException: Permission Denial: not allowed to send broadcast android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED from pid=13940, uid=2000
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1665)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:1618)
        at android.app.ActivityManagerProxy.broadcastIntent(ActivityManagerNative.java:3533)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.sendBroadcast(Am.java:772)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.onRun(Am.java:404)
        at com.android.internal.os.BaseCommand.run(BaseCommand.java:51)
        at com.android.commands.am.Am.main(Am.java:121)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.nativeFinishInit(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit.main(RuntimeInit.java:262)
```

Comment: Try this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/41084791/7746134

Comment: it does not work anyway

Comment: anyway the reboot of system should not be affected by app manifest

Comment: you try to run this commend in the host PC terminal, right?

Comment: the one on the left of logcat

Comment: Are you using a physical device or an emulator ?

Comment: physical : huawei p 90 light

Comment: That's why you can't run adb in root mode as advised in the thread linked earlier. Try with an emulator, one that does not use the Google Play Services if I recall correctly

Comment: it doesn't work even on emulator

Comment: Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43923996/adb-root-is-not-working-on-emulator). Alternatively, if it's only for the sake of testing, can you try using another intent to fake a reboot ?

Comment: it does not work equally on both "root" and the fake intent

Comment: `android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED` is not for rebooting, it's an intent sent by the system when the device has completed booting. You cannot send it because it is a system action; you need root to send it.

Answer (score 0):

That broadcast won't work as it is a system privileged `Intent`.  If you just need to restart your app clean in a certain activity, the `am` command has an option to force stop the running process (`-S`) before delivering the `Intent`:

```
adb shell am -S -a "android.action.MAIN" -c "android.category.DEFAULT" -n "your.package.name/.YourActivityName"
```

Comment: i don need to restart the app. I need to fire the event of the reboot of the sistem, without closing/opening manuall operations.

Comment: OK, that was not clear from your question.  You cannot directly simulate boot complete by sending that `Intent`.  The system only allows it to be sent by the internal Android framework.